# Entity Framework 7 Accessing Entity Objects inside ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have two entities Users and Addresses. Addresses is an ICollection property on the Users entities. However i am not able to access the individual addresses inside the ICollection. Is that possible and i just have the wrong syntax or does entity framework not allow that.

The Code:

Users:

```
 public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
        Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public long? UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Addresses:

```
public partial class Address
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Repository (Parent):

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private DemoContext _context;

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DemoContext context)
    {
        _context =context;
        DbSet = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual T Get(int Id)
    {
        // TODO: Implement with return of DbSet.Find();

        // DbSet.Find(Id);
        return null;
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T user)
    {
        _context.Entry<T>(user)
            .State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(int Id)
    {
        // TODO: Implement with return of DbSet.Find();

        // DbSet.Remove(Dbset.Find(Id));
    }
```

UserRepository:

```
 public class UserRepository : Repository<User>
{
    public UserRepository(DemoContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public override User Get(int Id)
    {
        return DbSet
            .Where(o => o.Id == Id)
            .Include(o => o.Orders)
            .Include(o => o.Addresses)
            .ToList()
            .Single();
    }

    public override List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet
            .Include(o => o.Orders)
            .Include(o => o.Addresses)
            .ToList();
    }

    public override void Delete(int Id)
    {     
        DbSet.Remove(Get(Id));
    }
}
```

The following code will not give me access to the first address in the ICollection property on the user entity

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var user = userRepository.Get(1);

        var order = new Order
        {
            Address = user.Addresses[0].Address,
            City = user.Addresses[0].City,
            State = user.Addresses[0].State,
            Zip = user.Addresses[0].Zip,
            User = user,
            SubTotal = 100,
            Tax = 25,
            Total = 125
        };

        orderRepository.Add(order);
        orderRepository.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Please advise on how to correct my code so i have access to the entities in the collection.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or null in the addresses?

Comment: Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ICollection<Addresses>

Comment: Try user.addresses.first().adress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering how i solved this here is the answer:

As mentiond by COLD TOLD ICollection does not support array like indexing. However Lists do so change it to a List instead of an ICollection and deleted the hashset that was created in the custructor

```
 public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public long? UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to access those nested entities as like this:

```
[HttpGet("/")]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var user = userRepository.Get(1);

    var order = new Order
    {
        Address = user.Addresses[0].Address1,
        City = user.Addresses[0].City,
        State = user.Addresses[0].State,
        Zip = user.Addresses[0].Zip,
        User = user,
        SubTotal = 100,
        Tax = 25,
        Total = 125
    };

    orderRepository.Add(order);
    orderRepository.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it a good idea to have that many includes in your select it might cause problems in your performance , you might try to change the order of the query

```
 return DbSet.Include(o => o.Orders)
            .Include(o => o.Addresses)
            .Where(o => o.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't seem to work for me. Im getting the Following Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ICollection<Addresses>

Comment: maybe that because the collection does not support array like indxing

Comment: how do i index into a collection?

Comment: you can try user.Addresses.ToArray()[0].Address,;